# Restricting the length of a double field in SQL

Tags: sql, mysql

I don´t have a field as such, but I am making a new field which is the result dividing an existing field, i.e. cost/1.15

Is there a way to restrict the result of this calculation to two decimal places?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change the column type to a [`NUMERIC(p, 2)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html) where p is the precision, especially if it is money (I'm guessing from `cost` that it might be money).

Also making a column which is derived from another column is generally a bad idea as the two can get out of sync. Consider making a view instead.

Comment: Hmm, is decimal more precise than double? Would I use decimal as such DECIMAL(cost/1.15, 2, 2) ?

Comment: @Blogbeard: I couldn't decide ;)  I've settled for *could*. I was tempted to write *should*, but there is insufficient information in the question to be sure that's what he wants.

Comment: @Jacob: It's a column type not a calculation. I've updated my answer to make it more clear. Try following the link for more info.

Comment: @Jacob: Decimal is in general *NOT* more precise than `double`, and much slower than `double`.  However, it can *exactly* represent decimal fractions like 0.01, which a binary type cannot.  This is why decimal types are recommended for storing amounts of money.

Comment: I can´t actually make new columns as I am in the confines of a CMS, I can choose columns within the CMS to display and assign them an sql query, but can´t actually create new columns or views..

Comment: @mark: so DECIMAL(cost/1.15, 2, 2) would be correct given my constraints?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need the [`ROUND()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round) function.

Eg. `ROUND(cost/1.15, 2)`